# Random Content Script with Random Timed Delay

Tags: php, cron

At the moment I have a really basic PHP script for randomly drawing quotes from a text file.

```
<?php include('testimonials.txt');
  srand ((double) microtime() * 100000);
  $random_number = rand(0,count($quotes)-1);
  echo ($quotes[$random_number]);
?>
```

Of course currently the script executes every time the page loads and brings up new content each time the page is refreshed.

I want to know is there any easy way to modify this to change the content on a timer, so it only changes once a day, or every few days?

If it requires altering the wp-cron.php of my site, any idea what I would need to put in there to do so?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start with something as basic as this, which saves the id of a quote and the time it was picked in a file:

```
<?php
$cachefile = './current_t_id';
$time = $id = null; // assume we have no cached quote
$change_every = 3600; // seconds
include('testimonials.txt');

// if cached quote exists, load it
if(is_file($cachefile)) {
    list($time, $id) = explode(' ', file_get_contents($cachefile));
}

// if no cached quote or duration expired, change it
if(!$time || time() - $time > $change_every) {
    srand ((double) microtime() * 100000);
    $id = rand(0,count($quotes)-1);
    file_put_contents($cachefile, time().' '.$id); // update cache
}

// echo the quote, be it cached or freshly picked 
echo ($quotes[$id]);
```

There are several things that can be improved here (e.g. error handling, the possibility of the testimonials file changing in a way that makes the cached quote invalid, etc) but the basic idea should be apparent.

Comment: I tried the script, but it still seems to change every time the screen is refreshed. Am I wrong is saying want I want can't be achieved without storing the information in some sort of database? If so, do you have any clues as to where i might be able to find some info on how to do it? thank you :)

Comment: @LukeTetrabyte: Works fine for me. If it doesn't work for you the only explanation is that saving the cache file fails. Find out why and fix it.

Comment: should the cache file be in a database? (if so what do I need to call the DB to get the script to communicate?) Or should it be along side the script in same directory, if so what should the file extention be?

Sorry if it sounds noobish :)

Comment: @LukeTetrabyte: Files cannot be in databases, (totally unrelated abstract concepts) but you can of course store the same information in a database. There are lots of beginner tutorials online. For a file: the location, name and extension are something you get to pick.

Comment: Okay awesome thanks, a cache file would be much easier. so do I just replace $cachefile = './current_t_id'; with the cache file name and extension?

Comment: @LukeTetrabyte: Yes. Put in a nice writable path too.

Comment: Thank you :) Do you mean writable by setting the file permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to persistently store some variables, either in a [database](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php), flat file or somewhere else.

For example, you could store the time the quote was last updated, as well as the current quote id. When loading the page, you check if the time difference is greater than some amount of time (e.g. 1 day, 2 days etc) and if it is generate a new quote id. Otherwise, just get the current quote id and display it.